# Firebase returns "no-referrer-when-downgrade" when accessing profile photo for account that was deleted then recreated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a react app that lets users login with Google using Firebase auth.

I logged in with Google successfully and it shows my profile image.

Then I deleted the account from Firebase auth, re-logged in to my app with the same Google account, and now it gives me this error instead of showing the profile image:

```
Request URL: https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-X2-ldAeMA_0/etc.../photo.jpg
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 403 
Remote Address: 172.217.13.161:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Yet I can see the image when simply navigating to the https://lh6.googleusercontent.com URL from an incognito window, or by logging into my app as an anonymous user.

Any ideas about what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue -- waited a couple of minutes and then it started working again. I.e. Looks like there's some account management clean-up that Firebase/Google does on the back-end that is a bit slow and causes problems if you re-create the account 'too quickly'.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, adding this, `referrerPolicy="no-referrer`, to the  tag where the `photoURL` is being called worked for me.